# How to select distinct columns and return non null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, distinct

I have many tables that has a relationship to one main table.
I want to be able to join these tables, while selecting distinct values from each row, and return only the non null values is this possible?

For example,

```
 ColA    ColB    ColC
 Black   3       Car
 Red     18      60
```

Here is my query so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FormTitle, FormSection FROM Table1 c
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 l
   ON c.FormSectionID = l.FormSectionID
FULL OUTER JOIN Table3 f
   ON c.FormID = f.FormID
```

I want the FormTitle column to have all distinct and non null values and the same for the FormSection column etc.

Here are my results when I add WHERE FormTitle IS NOT NULL AND FormSection IS NOT NULL

```
FormTitle                                   FormSection
Activities                                  Activities
Annual Program Data Demographic             Demographics
Annual Program Data Screening and Outreach  Other Diseases (Not Eligible for RECA)
Annual Program Data Screening and Outreach  Outreach/Education Encounters
Annual Program Data Screening and Outreach  Program Activities by Type
Annual Program Data Screening and Outreach  RECA-Eligible Diseases by Exposure Category
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with NULL use the `IS NULL` or the `IS NOT NULL`

```
 SELECT DISTINCT FormTitle, FormSection 
 FROM Table1 c
 FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 l
   ON c.FormSectionID = l.FormSectionID 
 FULL OUTER JOIN Table3 f
  ON c.FormID = f.FormID
 WHERE FormTitle IS NOT NULL 
   AND FormSection IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I just ran this and some FormTitles still have duplicate values

Comment: So there is no way to ensure that the columns are distinct as well?

Comment: What do you mean by distinct columns? You don't care if the values from different rows get returned in the same row?

Comment: @SeanLange I want the values in the column to be distinct

Comment: So you want the distinct values for each column and you don't care that they don't actually belong to the same row?

Comment: @SeanLange That is correct, because each column is coming from a different table

Comment: you really to display what you "want"..  what you are asking is not possible if you have 2 columns that can have different nbr of distinct values...

Comment: @T McKeown - sure you can. There is always a way. I will post a workable solution for this.

Comment: not having 2+ columns in the resultset... if you consolidated into 1 column then yes of course...

Answer (score 0):

This is a strange request but it can be done. The performance on something like this is not going to be spectacular but on a small dataset it shouldn't be much of an issue. I used your example posted to help. It would be very helpful if you could post ddl and sample in a consumable format like this.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Something') is not null
    drop table #Something

create table #Something
(
    Title varchar(50),
    FormSection varchar(50)
)

insert #Something
select 'Activities', 'Activities' union all
select 'Annual Program Data Demographic', 'Demographics' union all
select 'Annual Program Data Screening and Outreach', 'Other Diseases (Not Eligible for RECA)' union all
select 'Annual Program Data Screening and Outreach', 'Outreach/Education Encounters' union all
select 'Annual Program Data Screening and Outreach', 'Program Activities by Type' union all
select 'Annual Program Data Screening and Outreach', 'RECA-Eligible Diseases by Exposure Category';

with Titles as
(
    select Title, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) as RowNum
    from #Something
    group by Title
)
, FormSections as
(
    select FormSection, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by (select null)) as RowNum
    from #Something
    group by FormSection
)

select FormSection, Title
from
(
    select FormSection, Title
    from FormSections fs
    left join Titles t on fs.RowNum = t.RowNum

    union all

    select FormSection, Title
    from Titles t
    left join FormSections fs on fs.RowNum = t.RowNum
) x
group by FormSection, Title
```